# Not receiving Focus or Window events in an Applet

Tags: java, applet, windowlistener, focuslistener

I have a Java Applet (using the JApplet class) and I'm trying to get an event when the Applet window is activated. I have tried to implement WindowListener and FocusListener, but I do not receive any events. What do I need to do to figure out if the applet window has received focus?

Here is my test code:

```
public class AppletTest extends JApplet implements WindowListener, FocusListener {
    public void init() { 
//        addWindowListener(this); // Won't compile
        addFocusListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        Object source = event.getSource();
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println("focusGained");
    }
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("windowActivated");
    }
    // Stub methods 
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding:
setFocusable(true);

to the init method should fix your issue.

Comment: That does indeed fix the problem I asked, thank you!

Comment: However, in my production code, which is significantly more complicated, that is not always fired. I also have modeless JPanel’s in my applet. If one of those JPanel’s is on top, and I click on the main applet window, the focusGained event is not fired. Is there any way to get an event when my main Applet window is brought to the top of the zOrder?